# Convergence of sequence in relative topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence in $X = [0,1) \times [0,1)$ so that $x_{n} = (\frac{n-1}{n},\frac{n-1}{n}) ,\forall$ n $\in \mathbb{ N} $ . Is $(x_{n})$ convergent if we have dictionary order topology on $X$? What about if we have relative topology on $X$ to dictionary order topology on $ \mathbb{R^2} $?

I guess the sequence would converge towards $(1,1)$, but as  $(1,1) \notin X$, how do I prove that it doesn't converge?

Comment: Even in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ in the dictionary order topology this sequence would not converge to any point, certainly not to $(1,1)$ which has basic neighbourhoods of the form $((1,r),(1,1)]$ which contains no elements of the sequence at all.

Comment: $X$ is not closed, so the limit point of this sequence is not in $X$.  What are you looking for?

Comment: @herbsteinberg To be precise, it is actually worse than that. Even if we took $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ and gave it the dictionary order topology, the sequence still won't have **any** limit points in that space, let alone $(1, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments: Suppose the sequence converges to $(x,y)\in X$ in dictionary order topology. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $(x,y)$ such that the $y$-coordinates of its elements have distance $\geq c>0$ from $1$ (if $x\neq0$ then one could e.g. take $U=(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\times\{y\}$ for $\varepsilon$ small enough).
Then $U$ contains only finitely many elements of the sequence, so it does not converge to $(x,y)$.